# Submit button setting a value in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, submit

I have to make a button which has a value that is a javascript variable

```
<script>
    for(i=0; i < count; i++) 
        {
            var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
            var cell = row.insertCell(0);
            cell.innerHTML = '<input type="submit" value=i onClick="someFunc(this.value)" />';
        }
</script>
```

But when i open the page the value is just i. How do set the value of i in the button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wouldn't it just be

```
cell.innerHTML = '<input type="submit" value="'+ i + '" onClick="someFunc(this.value)" />';
```

so you use the value of i instead of the string i?

Answer (score 0):

Here you are setting the value of button by wrong method..

```
<script>
for(i=0; i < count; i++) 
    {
        var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
        var cell = row.insertCell(0);
        cell.innerHTML = '<input type="submit" value='+i+' onClick="someFunc(this.value)" />';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you assign i into quotes its take as a string. Not a variable. So u can use  `'+i+'` .

**+** Concatenation Operator

```
<script>
for(i=0; i < count; i++) 
    {
        var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
        var cell = row.insertCell(0);
        cell.innerHTML = '<input type="submit" value='+i+' onClick="someFunc(this.value)" />';
    }
</script>
```